# ReactJS external library

Tags: reactjs, peoplepicker

Hi I am quite new to reactjs but I started to understand few things. But this one giving me a headache, I have a small reactjs component that will be added in an existing site. The problem is inside my component I wanted to use a function in a JS file that is declared masterpage of the site. The name of the function I want to access is "SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper", so whenever I build my component I get the following error :

> 'SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper' is not defined  no-undef

I tried using windom.SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper but the problem is in window "SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper" is giving me a different function. It would be nice if that library can be scoped inside my component

I tried calling library using import but it didnt work

```
import clientforms from "https://standardsSite.com/_layouts/15/clienttemplates.js";
```

Comment: Please share how that function is injected in your pare

Comment: Its a js file from SharePoint which is minified. Even I shared it I don't think it will be help. I tried adding it my project but webpack is thorwing hunders of error because of that js file

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem I use loadjs its very handy.

```
loadjs(
  [
    "https://mysharepointsite.com/_layouts/15/clienttemplates.js",
    "https://mysharepointsite.com/_layouts/15/clientforms.js",
    "https://mysharepointsite.com/_layouts/15/clientpeoplepicker.js",
    "https://mysharepointsite.com/_layouts/15/autofill.js"
  ],
  "SPLibrary"
);
let self = this;
loadjs.ready("SPLibrary", function() {
  self.handleSubmit(self.props.name);
});
```